# Admistration role lost for the default user "weblogic" in oracle webcenter content 12c, not able to login into webcenter console

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, webcenter

I have lost the administration role for the default user "weblogic" in Oracle WebCenter content thus not able to login into the WebCenter console and Enterprise management.

[image]
screenshot when login with the `weblogic` user in managed server(/cs). The administration tab got lost.

[image]
screenshot when login with the `weblogic` user in the console and getting error 403 permission denied with the statement:

> "User is not authorized to use this feature. To use this feature, you
>   must have the administrator role. Please LOGIN again."

Please help out as this was strange that the administration access got lost. I can not take much risk with the restart of the server as if it is stopped(by killing the process id, since weblogic is not having admin access now so can't getting stop by normal procedure) it might not start and block people who are working with contributor role.

Answer (score 0):

```
export MW_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw
export DOMAIN_HOME=$MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/prod
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar
. $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
cd $DOMAIN_HOME/security/
mv DefaultAuthenticatorInit.ldift DefaultAuthenticatorInit.ldift.old
java weblogic.security.utils.AdminAccount <username> <password> .
cd $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/data/
mv ldap ldap_old
nano $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties

nohup sh $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/startWebLogic.sh &
```

- https://bitbucket.org/snippets/jhult/ebrGd
- http://www.snapdba.com/2010/05/how-to-reset-the-weblogic-admin-server-password/

Answer (score 0):

- From your directory (C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home_1221\user_projects\domains\gateway_domain1\bin), 
  run “setDomainEnv.sh” or “setDomainEnv.cmd"
- From your security directory inside your domain(C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home_1221\user_projects\domains\gateway_domain1\security)
  run **java weblogic.security.utils.AdminAccount   .**
- From your servers directory (C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home_1221\user_projects\domains\gateway_domain1\servers\AdminServer), rename the data folder to something like data_old
- similarly inside your security directory, rename boot.properties to boot.properties_old
- create a boot.properties file to avoid prompting in weblogic and enter your new username and password there without space or tabs.
  username=adminusername
  password=adminpassword

  - now, restart your weblogic and login using new admin creds